# Is there a method to solve the following diophantine equation: $2x^2+2y^2+2z^2 +u^2 +v^2 = N$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Just to give a simple numerical example but in general the variables $x,y,z,u,v$ are not equal.

$113= 2*4^2 + 2*4^2 +2*4^2 + 4^2 +1^2$

I am looking for a general method to solve this type of equation or a piece of software to do the same. I already looked in this site for methods that could help but could not find anything dealing with this ind of case.

**Question 2** It is also useful to know if there is a test that can tell if the equation does not have a solution.

Comment: Use brute force, you'll have to write the code yourself

Comment: Check http://wolframalpha.com, but your equation is too long, unelse if you assume that $x=y=z$ as you use in your example

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua, in general, the variables $x,y,z$ are not equal. I will add this detail to the post. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some [brutal code](https://tio.run/##Vc9LbsIwEAbgdX2KEVUlv2gxXZr0BCgb1FXLIjUEIiWhdWzLDuLqTZ0QKEiWZvR/Y8ujpjuluu6xqFVpN1tYNGZTHJ73b@guKouv@6zKzL5PUFEbqLKixn2T6Z3ioPaZBhp797Em6IgAekshgcZoc7AlHkysefq@XHIxI3KcqTIv4pjaFiVufrTBKSFM3Oj8Xl/mt@554C233PGVRA8xzA8a@2QmwS/6u7EyRmI@QEi8hDBCGGGQNgkS2lHaiwxk@9dsTyLWKw3mEivBjeb@7ThWgFX8/ZxiTz0LNLCWtoRZapmjTl6HihzHuQRSAt86rpXjydMGzgfO9bOe8Ouy5HL1hCB2emusrmEm0anrOiFef1VeZrumm5bVHw) (understand not optimized at all) to get all solutions as a verification.

Since $x,y,z$ and $u,v$ are symmetric, I did not print the shuffles.

There is always at least one solution if we allow some of the variables to be zero:

- for $n$ odd set $x=y=0$ then $n=2z^2+u^2+v^2$ has a solution, see this  [representing all odd naturals as the sum of four squares, two of them equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68225/3992633)
- for $n=2p$ even set $u=v$ and we get $x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2=p$ which has a solution by [Lagrange four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

It seems to me with $5$ unknowns there is plenty of room to have solutions, so it might be difficult to express them all unless using brute force.

Comment: @zwin, can you please run your code for $N=181$. I tried to run it but I am missing probably many things and I just don't know how to fix it. thanks.

Comment: Just put $181$ in place of $113$ and hit the button "circled triangle" at the top, on the right of TIO.

Comment: I just want to mention that your code can be used to factor integers or prove they are prime. Let me know if you want to discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

$$ u^2 + v^2 +2 x^2+ 2 y^2 $$ is positive universal. Thus, take
$$ z = \left\lfloor \sqrt \frac{N}{2} \right\rfloor   $$

after which $N- 2 z^2$ is fairly small, search any way you like in finishing
$$   N - 2 z^2 =  u^2 + v^2 +2 x^2+ 2 y^2  $$